# next-routes server.js fails: TypeError: routes.getRequestHandler is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I am getting an error in server.js. My script looks like this:

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const next = require('next');
const routes = require('./routes');

const app = next ({
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
});

const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(app);

app.prepare().then( () =>{
  createServer(handler).listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Ready on localhost:3000');
  });
});
```

It is pretty much copied straight out of the next-routes documentation.
This is what I get when I run >npm run dev

```
C:\Users\zangezi39\kickstart\server.js:9

const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(app);
                ^                       
TypeError: routes.getRequestHandler is not a function

    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zangezi39\kickstart\server.js:9:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! kickstart@1.0.0 dev: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the kickstart@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a custom server? It doesn't seems to be required in your case. Please see doc: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I definitely do need it. Fortunately I was able to get it to work (just needed to complete the routes.js script, although in the course I am doing this for it was supposed to work as is)

Answer (score 2):

you must change routes.js script

Please check if `const routes = require('next-routes');` change it to
`const routes = require('next-routes')();`

Answer (score 1):

it not like that.
look at this

```
const next = require('next');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });

const handler = app.getRequestHandler();
```

Comment: This solution will solve the issue but it wont be possible to use the 'pushRoute' on Router

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot a `,` in the end of this line `dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'`.

Here is the code that works for me:

```
 const {createServer} = require('http');
    const next = require('next');

    const app = next({
     dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    });

    const routes = require('./routes');
    const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(app);

    app.prepare().then(() => {
      createServer(handler).listen(3000, (err) => {
       if (err) throw err;
         console.log('Ready on localhost: 3000');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, I fixed when I have `routes.js`  on the same level as `server.js`, also you should make sure that `routes.js` looks like this

```
const routes = require('next-routes')();
module.exports = routes
```

Many programmers forget to export the routes module at the end, so you should have `'module.exports = routes'` in your `routes.js`
Also go to `package.json` file and check if you installed `next` and `next-routes` module

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `()` at the end of
`const routes = require("next-routes")'()'`
in `routes.js` file